# MacOS sTerminal Commands

Tags: macos, terminal, command

If I'm opening an xcode project in terminal, and the command to open it is

> open -a Xcode a.xcodeproj
> what does the -a mean? Are there more commands like this? And what do they mean?

Thanks!

Trying to learn more about terminal commands

Comment: Terminal commands are part of the operating system, and questions about them are not programming-related, which makes them off-topic at SO. You should ask this sort of question for MacOS at [apple.se], or general computer questions at [su] instead. For more information about what is appropriate to ask at SO, see the [help].

Answer (score 2):

The `-a` to the `open` command is an example of a flag.

The flags for the `open` command on MacOS can be viewed by running:

`man open`

Which has the following in it's output

```
     -a application
         Specifies the application to use for opening the file
```

In your above example, you are explicitly specifying to open using the `Xcode` application for your file.

Answer (score 0):

So, open -a Xcode a.xcodeproj, the -a is a flag used with the open command. It  is a general flag used with the open command in macOS.

There are other flags which can be used with the open command:

-e: Opens the file with the default text editor.
-t: Opens the file with the default text editor as a new document.
-b: Opens the file with a specific application bundle identifier.
-R: Reveals the file in the Finder without opening it.

You can try the "man" command in the terminal to access the manual pages for the open command.